# Network administration has blocked logging in to Stack Overflow sites

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, career-development

I'm working on a software development company. Most of time I spend my time in StackOverflow and other related network sites. 
Today I noticed that Network administration has blocked us from login into StackOverflow user accounts. I can't go to login page. 
I am allowed only to visit the site as a visitor. 
Most of the time I was chatting in chat rooms. They might have tracked this.

*should I talk to IT head regarding this matter?*

If I do so, how should I justify the reason to be able to logged into the StackOverflow user account?

I feel so frustrated right now.
Should I look for another place? If so,  will it be a reasonable fact as a programmer?

Comment: What's your goal, to find another job? Or to get them to unblock it? It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here..

Comment: What did you talk about in the chatrooms?

Comment: "Most of time I spend my time in StackOverflow and other related network sites." is that what generates value for your company and what you are paid for?

Comment: most likely they didn't block SO at all, but the 3rd party service you use to authenticate yourself with SO, be it Yahoo, Google, Facebook, etc.

Comment: @enderland either of those. I know I paid for do some work. But just because of that is it legal to restrict things like these?

Comment: From your user page it looks like you've used StackOverflow on several occasions to get answers to work related problems. Is that true?

Comment: @freekvd no. Those posts are related to my other college projects.

Comment: see also: [Team members spending too much time on Stack Overflow](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/team-members-spending-too-much-time-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: "is it legal to restrict things like these?" <-- It's your company's network, they obviously can make the rules on what you can and can't access. Besides, it's not like the site is truly "blocked" as you can still access the questions and answers - searching questions/answers for work-related issues is probably about 100x more legitimate to use at work than using the chat feature.

Comment: @Brandin Agreed. The issue I see is that it complicates asking questions but that doesn't seem to be what bothers the OP.

Comment: You are allowed to visit the site as a guest, that is usually good enough to get answers to programming questions. If you have to ask a question, you can still do it as an unregistered user. What is your problem?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan, this is going to shock you but there is no legal requirement that they allow you Internet access at all.

Comment: This might get a bit meta, but people suggesting the user can still post anonymous questions... sure.  But site reputation exists for a reason, right?  IN THEORY (not sure if SO has done research to back this up or not) having good reputation would mean better engagement with your questions versus anonymous user's questions?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan: another place like SO, or another place to work?

Comment: Voting to reopen as the other question was clearly about misuse of SO, while this question seems about a generic change in policy.  The accepted answer is nothing like any of the answers there.

Comment: @AndrewWhatever OP's employer doesn't let him use SO as a regular user, so he currently has only has two choices: 1. Ask questions as unregistered user or 2. Don't ask questions on SO. I did not "recommend" asking questions anonymously, just wanted to know what his specific problem is. If OP says, "I don't get good enough responses to my questions when asked anonymously, and that hampers my work", then that makes it somewhat easier to convince the employer. However, if his only problem is, "I am unable to chat in the chat rooms", that won't impress anyone enough to change their policy.

Comment: He has a 3rd choice, which is go to whomever is in charge and make the argument that he will get better response (again, not sure if this is provably TRUE but it seems likely) with a non-anonymous profile.  Not what I'd do in that situation, but it is a choice.  You're right though that it is unclear if this is even the angle he is coming from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two possible cases:

1. Your SO activity, including non-guest activity, is part of your job. If so, report the problem accessing SO just as you would any other network issue affecting your ability to do your job.
2. Your SO activity is for your own interest and development, not a necessary part of your job. If so, access it from home rather than work.

If you are not sure which case applies, discuss with your co-workers and/or your boss. If you do decide to report it, you should be sure that your boss will confirm your need for SO access if asked by IT.